# Powershell : Filter using regex and replace matched substring

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-3.0

This seems like a very basic thing to do, but I am new to PowerShell and can't figure this out or find an example online.

I am reading a `json` file and checking whether any key, value pair has double underscore(`__`) substring as value. I need to replace that substring with some actual value.

Suppose below is my json file.

```
"parameters": {
     "tenantId": {
         "value": "adf/__TENANT_ID_AG08__"
      }

 }
```

And I am trying with the below code to find any substring which starts and ends with double underscore(`__TENANT_ID_AG08__` in above example). It is unable to get any matches:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $dirPath -Recurse -Filter *.json | 
Foreach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName 

    #Get all the matches with __*ag*__ in a file and replace it with the actual values.
    # UNABLE to get any match. 
    $placeholders = $content | Where-Object {$_ -match '__*AG*__'} 
    
    
    foreach($placeholer in $placeholers) {
       
       #Logic to replace the substring. 
       #...
       #...
       #..
        
    }
}
```

Assuming, in the above example I have `__TENANT_ID_AG08__` value available which I read from the config file and I need to replace that substring.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `*` is a quantifier, `_*` matches zero or more `_` chars. You may use `.*` to match any text. Or `\w*` to match any 0 or more letters, digits or `_`

Comment: `-match` -> `-like`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the solution provided in the link does not seem to be working.

Comment: [It does](https://regex101.com/r/5KoEMm/1). [It does, too](https://regex101.com/r/5KoEMm/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried with `$placeholders = $content | Where-Object {$_ -match "__\w*AG\w*__"} ` and getting `"value": "adf/__TENANT_ID_AG08__" ` whereas I need only `__TENANT_ID_AG08__`.

Comment: If you want to *replace*, why `-match`? `| % {$_ -replace '__\w*AG\w*__', 'new_value'}`

Comment: First I need to read `__TENANT_ID_AG08__ ` value from another config file and then only I can replace it.